# Web browser most suitable for web development

Tags: browser

Which web browser is most suitable for web development? To be precise which browser has better and more add-ons supporting web development? Please tell me the corresponding add-ons also.

Comment: If you're talking about the add-on ecosystem alone, than of course it's Firefox. Of course there are a great deal many more factors to consider. I'd vote for Firefox too, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like Firefox + [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/). Chrome is alright, too.

Of course you need all major browsers installed to be sure your site works correctly.

This allows you to use multiple versions of IE and also comes in handy:
http://utilu.com/IECollection/

Comment: Plus Yahoo! Yslow firefox addon http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Comment: Agreed, the addition of Fiddler (http traffic inspector) really enhances low level debugging of network activity too

Answer (score 2):

**Firefox with Webdeveloper add-on pack** is the best of all.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Firefox, but you should probably have all the major ones installed for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to use firefox because it has Firebug, the developer toolbar, and Google's 'page speed' add-on.

Answer (score 0):

As said already I'd go for firebug and firefox.

I think chrome comes with much the same features as firebug out of the box.

You probably want to make sure your site works properly in more than one browser.

Not much point developing for IE though if your site is for mac users you know?

I remember a site that let you see what your page looked like in lots of different browsers, can't remember the name though.

I'm not a web developer, so feel free to disregard anything I say!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. If you can recall the name of the site you are talking about it could be a great help.

Comment: I think it was http://browsershots.org.


Unfortunately it looks like it's not totally free, you can pay for a priority service.

You enter the website you want and then screenshots are uploaded one by one.


http://browsershots.org/http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox, Chrome and IE all have "developer" extensions.  Each of which has its own quirks (both strengths and weaknesses). Firefox has the most extensions, and those which are the most stable.  This is due to the simple fact that Firefox has been in the extension business longer than Chrome or IE.

Personally, I use both Firefox and IE for testing web development--both using STOCK downloads. The reason for this, is that I don't typically need to look at HTML as much as I need the JS error console from FireFox. I use IE because it's still the dominant browser (especially in corporate scenarios which are my primary customer base), and I need to ensure my code works/looks good in IE.

Ultimately, you will need to try them and find which set of browsers (both default "abilities" and extensions) works best to help you locate the issues which your own idiosyncratic coding style may have. Also you need to know which browser your desired customer base is likely to use, and use that for testing.